# Problema con rutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Este es el contenido del fichero de rutas de laravel (web.php)

```
Route::prefix('compra')->group(function () {
    Route::get('usuario', 'FrontControllerCompras@pideUsuario');
    Route::post('consulta-usuario', 'FrontControllerCompras@consultaUsuario');
});
```

Tengo un problema con un formulario en una plantilla blade. Yo quiero enviar el formulario a una ruta post como la que pongo en el formulario y que tengo creada en el archivo rutas. Mi formulario es;

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'compra.consulta-usuario', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

La url del formulario es: http://localhost/compras/compra/usuario

El error que me sale al cargar la página es:

> Route [compra.consulta-usuario] not defined

Comment: safra, ¡Bienvenido al sitio!, primeramente te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio ¡y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla traduciéndola y que así cumpla con las normas del sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto es **muy importante leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)**, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La otra respuesta resuelve parcialmente el problema, pero promueve una mala práctica dentro de Laravel: usar URL en vez de nombres de rutas, por lo cual si decides cambiar la url en el archivo de rutas, deberás cambiarla en todas partes donde la escribas (en el formulario en este caso).

Si quieres usar el nombre de la ruta en el formulario (lo cual recomiendo), tan solo debes definir el nombre de la misma en el archivo de rutas:

```
Route::post('consulta-usuario', 'FrontControllerCompras@consultaUsuario')
    ->name('compra.consulta_usuario');
```

---

En cuanto a la otra respuesta, el segundo método que propone (utilizar `Route::resource`) es incorrecto en este caso, pues dicha sintaxis genera varias rutas básicas pero no va a generar el nombre de la ruta `compra.consulta_usuario`.

Comment: Exacto!! Eso es lo que me faltaba, poner el parametro name en la ruta. Muchas gracias!! Shaz.

Comment: bueno, dicen que hay mil formas de llegar a roma..

Comment: compra.consulta_usuario funcionaria si creara el controlador consulta_usuario

Comment: ¿crear un controlador? te invito a que revises el código en Laravel que genera las rutas REST, o te agradecería que me muestres en qué parte de la documentación o en el código está explicada la generación de rutas dinámicas con solo crear ¿controladores? @Franklin'jGil'z

Comment: quise decir el metodo en el controlador 'FrontControllerCompras@consulta_usuario'

Comment: En todo caso Laravel no genera URL solo porque agregues un método, a menos que me muestres alguna parte de la documentación o del código que yo no conozca.

Answer (score -1):

Usa:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'compra/consulta-usuario', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Si quieres usar `route` tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

En tu `web.php`

```
Route::resource('compra', 'FrontControllerCompras')
```

En tu `FrontControllerCompras.php` tienes que crear un metodo que se llame `consulta_usuarios`

y ahora ya puedes usar

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'compra.consulta_usuario', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Eso te debería funcionar...

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67064/discussion-on-answer-by-franklinj-gilz-route-problem-in-laravel).

Comment: @Franklin'j Gil'z Me ha funcionado con la primera opción. Lo que no entiendo es porque utilizando el route no me funcionaba si la ruta realmente si que existia. Gracias.

Comment: lo que pasa es que hay varios metodos... url, route y action... y cada uno tiene una sintaxis diferente..